# Ошибка подключения соединения к базе данных в проекте WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, visual-studio

Работаю над курсовым проектом, мне нужно создать приложение библиотеку.

Для этого мне нужно подключить базу данных, но при подключении выдает ошибку, не знаю что и делать с этой ошибкой, подскажите, что делать пожалуйста.

Сейчас будет проведена хронология действий приводящая к это ошибке

1.Создаю элемент

2.Выбираю конструктор

3.Создаю новое соединение

4.Вписываю имя сервера и выбираю бд KP

5.Ошибка

Раньше все было нормально, это можно увидеть на 3 картинки где уже соединена конкретная бд, а теперь не пойму почему другие бд и та же самая не соединяется

[image: Создаю элемент]

[image: Выбираю конструктор]

[image: Создаю новое соединение]

[image: Вписываю имя сервера и выбираю бд KP]

[image: И собственно вот]

Comment: Текст ошибки напишите текстом в посте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновил visual studio и все заработало)